# Is there an Exchange Server 2010 based service publicly available with EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server

I was asked to develop a connection to download emails from Exchange 2010 using EWS (Exchange Web Services). The company who asked does not have an Exchange server that is available from outside, but development and testing is impossible without having one. I also cannot and do not want to install and configure a full blown Exchange 2010 server because I do not have licenses and experience.

So the question: is there a publicly available email service that is using Exchange Server 2010 which can be accessed with EWS? I am willing to pay a fee for an account, so that's not a problem. I just want to save time and money with obtaining a license and learning to configure MSES2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/online-software.aspx free for one month. After that you can pay a few dollars per month to keep your account active.

I've used this service in the past and EWS is enabled.